# I need to create a javascript function in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

So basically I need to create a javascript function in visualforce where in it will check my input fields, If 1 input field has a value of 0 and I try to save it, It will throw a confirmation that I have a field that has a value of 0.

Can someone help me with this one.

```
<apex:page Controller="editLineItemSPRCOMM" cache="false" tabstyle="Opportunity" action="{!initAfter}">

<script type="text/javascript">


    function buttonValidate(){

       var showAlert = false;
     var zeroCheckInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id*=myNumber]');
    for (var i = 0; i < zeroCheckInputs.length; ++i)
    {
    if (zeroCheckInputs[i].value === '0') //Converting to an integer and comparing to 0 is somewhat more robust
    {
        markupFieldWithZero(zeroCheckInputs[i]);
        showAlert = true;
        alert("Yes");
    }
    }
if (showAlert)
    {
    alert("Some of your answers contain zero, please confirm they are correct");
    }

    }

    alert("Not Working");

    }


</script>

<apex:form id="form1" >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Line Item Calculator" id="aa">
        <apex:pageMessages id="pmsg"/>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >

            <apex:commandButton styleClass="butt1" value="Save and Return" action="{!saveLineItems}" onclick="buttonValidate()"/>
            <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Refresh" action="{!refreshLineItems}"/> -->

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <!-- Line Calculator for EMEA users -->


            <!--apex:column headerValue="Recommended End User Discount %"-->
            <apex:column headerValue="Rec. End User Disc %" id="ac">

                <apex:inputField value="{!myVar.item.Rec_EndUser_Disc__c}" id="myNumber">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!calculateRecEndUserPrice}" status="counterStatus"  rerender="table2,panel1,counterStatus,pmsg" id="aaa"/>
                </apex:inputField>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields inside tables and `apex:repeat` will have ids in `idsofparentelements:iterationnumber:idinmarkup`.  So, for example, `<apex:input type="number" id="myNumber">` will be generated with the ids `tableid:myNumber`, `tableid:1:myNumber`, and so on.  Knowing that, you can design a javascript function like:

```
function alertZeroes()
{
    var showAlert = false;
    var zeroCheckInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[id*=myNumber]');
    for (var i = 0; i < zeroCheckInputs.length; ++i)
    {
        if (zeroCheckInputs[i].value === '0') //Converting to an integer and comparing to 0 is somewhat more robust
        {
            markupFieldWithZero(zeroCheckInputs[i]);
            showAlert = true;
        }
    }
    if (showAlert)
    {
        alert("Some of your answers contain zero, please confirm they are correct");
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you want to put a message on the field and only display one alert, but obviously the iterative part of the function could be changed to do whatever you want to each element.  The `querySelectorAll` query should have `input` changed to `select` or `textarea` for picklist and multi-line text fields respectively.

Comment: cause what I was trying to do is, insert an id in a <apex:inputfield> and prolly just write a simple if and else statement in the javascript function. Like for example, (if "apex.inputfield == 0"){confirm("")}. Can you explain to me more briefly your solution? Well Actually my problem is that I don't know how to call my inputfields in the javascript function because it's inside of other apex component.

Comment: Because I want to throw different confirmation pop up depending on what field is 0 or null. @IllusiveBrian

Comment: I'm not sure how much briefer I can get.  If you put an `id` on your `apex:inputField` element, it will be generated with that `id` string near the end of its actual generated `id` attribute in `html`.  `input[id*=whatever]` will select only `input` elements that contain the `id` you put on the `apex:inputField`, regardless of where they are on the page.  From there, you can iterate over the collection with a `for` loop and check/do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I tried this one. In my <apex:inputField id="a"> and then in my javascript function. Var a =  var a = document.querySelectorAll ('input[id*=a]');
            alert(a);. But instead of throwing an alert with the value of a, it throws an [Object NodeList]; @IllusiveBrian

Comment: @JMDF Well, yeah, `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`.  See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).  That's why I iterate over the result in a `for` loop in my answer.  If you want to see if you are getting results, you could `alert(a.length)` and verify it is >0.  That said, I'd recommend you familiarize yourself with your browser's Developer Tools (F12 opens it on all browsers I've tried), and add `document.querySelectorAll ('input[id*=a]')` as a watch variable, that way you can see the collection you get back.

Comment: I actually tried your code. I just changed the id in my queryselectorforall to the id of my input field. When I try to hit save it just does not return anything, but when I change it to false it will just show the alert without checking the value of my inputfield.

Comment: Hi Brian I already edited my question. We can use as an example the <apex:inputField value="{!myVar.item.Rec_EndUser_Disc__c}" id="a">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!calculateRecEndUserPrice}" status="counterStatus"  rerender="table2,panel1,counterStatus,pmsg" id="aaa"/>
                </apex:inputField>

It's the first input field in my code above. When I try to input data in it and try to save, It will throw an confirmation alert where in it will check the values to 0.

Comment: Hi brian still waiting for your reply. Kinda stuck with this one, ran out of option to try and google. Thanks man

Comment: I forgot to set showAlert, and I also change condition since you are using an inputField which always renders a text input field.  Really, the best thing would be to verify if you are getting results from document.querySelectorAll first, then just modify my code to fit whatever results you get from your actual page.

Comment: I tried your code and it's just not throwing anything.

Comment: @JMDF At this point, you should edit your question with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47411/discussion-between-jmdf-and-illusivebrian).

Comment: Hi Brian Can we chat? Cause I badly needed this one thanks.

Comment: Cause basically What I did is just change the ID of my input field ID = a and then incorporate that with your code

Comment: Hi Brian I already edited my question.

Comment: Still waiting for your answer. Stuck with this one for days, can't find any solution and at the same time focused on other parts of my project atm. Can you help me please.

Comment: You have two issues - you have an extra curly brace at the end of your script tag (and alert("Not Working") is completely outside the function, as an aside), and never actually defined "markupFieldsWithZero", which I just put in as a placeholder for whatever you want to do with the fields that have zero as their value.

Comment: What do you mean by I should define "markupFieldsWithZero"?

Comment: can you show me how I can fix the issue from above. @IllusiveBrian. Thank you so much